# React-router nested rotues

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is how my Routing looks:

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
       <IndexRoute component={EventAppContainer}/>
       <Route path="fights" component={FightApp}/>
       <Route path="fighters" component={FightersAppContainer}>
         <Route path="/fighter/:id" component={FighterDetails} />
       </Route>
     </Route>
   </Router>
```

In FightersAppContainer I fetch some data, if I render everything from there my nested route works perfectly. But If I want to have more children components, for example FightersAppContainer=>FightersApp=>FighterItem then I cannot reach my nested route. I do not get any error it just doesn't show up. How can I fix this?

To be more clear if I use `<Link to={"/fighter/"+fighter.id}>{fighter.last_name}</Link>` inside FightersAppContainer I achieve what I want. But if I try that inside for example FighterItem component (that is a child of FightersAppContainer component) then I don't get the desired result, as a matter of fact I don't get anything including errors...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this:

```
<Route path="/fighter/:id" component={FighterDetails} />
```

being a child of the fighters path, would be expecting the route to be /fighters/fighter/:id, so your `Link` element would have to look like this if you're not on the fighters element itself:

```
<Link to={"/fighters/fighter/"+fighter.id}>{fighter.last_name}</Link>
```

Comment: If I use `<Link to={"/fighter/"+fighter.id}>{fighter.last_name}</Link>` I get nothing, but if I use your proposed solution I get in the console Warning: [react-router] Location "/fighters/fighter/465945" did not match any routes

Comment: Hopefully I was clear, if I use my Link inside FightersAppContainer it works but if I use it inside a child component (of FightersAppContainer) then I it still "works", meaning I don't get any errors it just won't output anything, unlike when I try any other link then it gives me the above mentioned warning